# Rails3 - Validate a unique pair of indexes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, indexing, validation

I created an index in my migrations:

`add_index "enrollments", ["student_id", "lecture_id"], :name => "index_enrollments_on_student_id_and_lecture_id", :unique => true`

How is it possible to validate this pair of keys in Rails? I tried:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :enrollment_id, :scope => [:student_id, :lecture_id]
```

But it doesn't work properly.

Also, I need to find out in a view, if this key already exists, or if it is possible to create a new entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base    
  validates_uniqueness_of :student_id, :scope => :lecture_id
end
```

If you want to determine in the view before submitting new enrollment that this pair exists then you can use ajax request (I prefer RJS with JQuery) and check it with:

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base    
  def self.pair_exists?(student_id, lecture_id)
    Enrollment.find_all_by_student_id_and_lecture_id(student_id, lecture_id).any?
  end
end
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for opening an old thread but since it's 2011 and I still couldn't find a proper validator, I created one myself:

```
class UniqueSetValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    setup record
    record.errors[attribute] << "- collection of fields [" + @fields + "] is not unique" if record.class.count(:conditions => @conditions) > 0
  end

  def check_validity!
    raise ArgumentError, "Must contain an array of field names' symbols" unless options[:in] && options[:in].respond_to?(:each)
  end

  private

  def setup record
    conditions  = []
    fields      = []

    options[:in].each do |field|
      conditions  |= [ field.to_s + " = '" + record[field].to_s + "'" ]
      fields      |= [ field.to_s ]
    end

    @conditions = conditions.join(" AND ")
    @fields     = fields.join(", ")
  end
end
```

It seems to work to me. To use it paste the code into:

```
your_rails_app/lib/unique_set_validator.rb
```

and enable it in:

```
your_rails_app/config/application.rb
```

by adding this line:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib  )
```

Then you can simply use it in your model:

```
validates :field, :unique_set => [ :field, :field2 ]
```

It will validate the uniqueness of pair [ :field, :field2 ], and any error would be returned to :field. I haven't tried but it should work for more that 2 fields.

I hope that I didn't messed up anything, and that this will help someone. :)

Comment: the answer by Voldy showed a correct approach in 2010. using `validates_uniqueness_of :field, scope: :field2` will validate that a pair of values is unique in the database, additional source [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870961/rails-validate-uniqueness-of-multiple-columns) and [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of)

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
validates_uniqueness_of :enrollment_id, student_id, :scope => [:student_id, :lecture_id], :lecture_id], :message => "combination of enrollment, student and lecture should be unique."
```

If combination of student and lecture is not unique than you will get message in your error messages.

Update:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :student_id, :scope => [:lecture_id], :message => "combination of student and lecture should be unique."
```

The way voldy define in answer that's the correct way.

Comment: In Enrollment model there is `id`, not `enrollment_id` and it's always unique.