# Validate uniqueness of multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Is there a rails-way way to validate that an actual record is unique and not just a column?  For example, a friendship model / table should not be able to have multiple identical records like:

```
user_id: 10 | friend_id: 20
user_id: 10 | friend_id: 20
```

Comment: try using "validates_uniqueness_of" in your model. if this doesnt work the try to create an index on which you can create a migration of feilds which includes a statement like 
   add_index  :table, [:column_a, :column_b], :unique => true)

Comment: Unfortunately `validates :field_name, unique: true` is prone to race conditions, so even though against rails-way, an actual constraint is prefered. @HarryJoy I'll upvote an answer describing constraint way.

Comment: @Green To be fair, that's an excellent way of ensuring that it will NEVER happen. Validations can be bypassed.

Comment: better answer then all the noted below is this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/34425284/1612469 as it brings another layer for making sure everything will work correctly

Answer (score 323, accepted):

You can scope a `validates_uniqueness_of` call as follows.

```rb
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :friend_id
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that you can pass multiple scope params in case you need to validate uniqueness on more than 2 fields. I.e. :scope => [:friend_id, :group_id]

Comment: Weird that you cannot say `validates_uniqueness_of [:user_id, :friend_id]`. Maybe this needs to be patched?

Comment: Alexey, validates_uniqueness_of [:user_id, :friend_id] will just do the validation for each of fields listed - and it is documented and expected behavior

Comment: In Rails 4, this becomes: validates :user_id, uniqueness: {scope: :friend_id}

Comment: You probably want to add a custom error msg like , :message => ' has already this friend.'

Comment: a unique SQL index should also be used as there is too much magic going on in rails' validators to rely them solely IMO, e.g. try validating a boolean value

Comment: @DaveRapin for the sake of new comers, what do you think of adding a migration adding an index to your answer, along the lines of the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424154/rails-validate-uniqueness-of-two-columns-together/34425284#34425284) (most programmers will recognise that race conditions could still be a risk here, but many may not)

Answer (score 158):

You can use [`validates`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates) to validate `uniqueness` by one column:

```
validates :user_id, uniqueness: {scope: :friend_id}
```

The syntax for the validation by multiple columns is similar, but you should provide an array of fields instead:

```
validates :attr, uniqueness: {scope: [:attr1, ... , :attrn]}
```

---

*However*, validation approaches shown above have a race condition and can’t ensure consistency. Consider the following example:

1. database table records are supposed to be unique by *n* fields;
2. multiple (*two or more*) concurrent requests, handled by separate processes each (*application servers, background worker servers or whatever one is using*), access database to insert the same record in table;
3. each process in parallel validates if there is a record with the same *n* fields;
4. validation for each request is passed successfully, and each process creates a record in the table with the same data.

To avoid this kind of behaviour, one should add a *unique constraint* to db table. You can set it with [`add_index`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index) helper for one (or multiple) field(s) by running the following migration:

```
class AddUniqueConstraints < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   add_index :table_name, [:field1, ... , :fieldn], unique: true
  end
end
```

*Caveat* : even after you've set a unique constraint, two or more concurrent requests will try to write the same data to db, but instead of creating duplicate records, this will raise an [`ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordNotUnique.html) exception, which you should handle separately:

```
begin
# writing to database
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e
# handling the case when record already exists
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a database constraint on the two columns:

`add_index :friendships, [:user_id, :friend_id], unique: true`

You could use a rails validator, but in general I recommend using a database constraint.

More reading: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/validation-database-constraint-or-both