# Rails: Validate unique combination of 3 columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I wan't to validate the unique combination of 3 columns in my table.

Let's say I have a table called cars with the values :brand, :model_name and :fuel_type.

What I then want is to validate if a record is unique based on the combination of those 3. An example:

```
    brand    model_name    fuel_type
    Audi     A4            Gas
    Audi     A4            Diesel
    Audi     A6            Gas
```

Should all be valid. But another record with 'Audi, A6, Gas' should NOT be valid.

I know of this validation, but I doubt that it actually does what I want.

```
    validates_uniqueness_of :brand, :scope => {:model_name, :fuel_type}
```

Comment: Don't doubt. Your validation is right

Comment: Hmm okay - just thought that what it did was to check if :brand is unique within a group on :model_name, :fuel_type

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails validate uniqueness of multiple columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870961/rails-validate-uniqueness-of-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 131, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code snippet. The correct validation is :

```
validates_uniqueness_of :car_model_name, :scope => [:brand_id, :fuel_type_id]
```

or even shorter in ruby 1.9.x:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :car_model_name, scope: [:brand_id, :fuel_type_id]
```

with **rails 4** you can use:

```
validates :car_model_name, uniqueness: { scope: [:brand_id, :fuel_type_id] }
```

with **rails 5** you can use

```
validates_uniqueness_of :car_model_name, scope: %i[brand_id fuel_type_id]
```

Comment: Is the rails 4 example really correct?  I'd think it should be something like:  `validates :brand_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:fuel_type_id] }` (i.e. don't reference the model name).

Comment: :model_name Is referencing the OP's question about car models lol not the model class :P

Comment: Oh yeah, that was misleading :(

Answer (score 18):

Depends on your needs you could also to add a constraint (as a part of table creation migration or as a separate one) instead of model validation:

```
add_index :the_table_name, [:brand, :model_name, :fuel_type], :unique => true
```

Adding the unique constraint on the database level makes sense, in case multiple database connections are performing write operations at the same time.

Comment: When I tried this, it appears that the unique constraint it put on all columns individually

Comment: This works, however if someone tries to save a duplicated entry the server will respond with an Internal Server Error (500) message, which is not a desired behavior. To avoid this you need to add the validation at the Model level, that way it will respond with an error message just like any other validation.

Comment: @tafuentesc you write the controller so you decide what will be the server response. You can wrap your code with `rescue` (try-catch) and respond on Duplicate error the way you want.

Comment: As @tafuentesc mentioned it's highly recommended to add a validation in the model to prevent from raising `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` error, at least in **Rails 5**. The validations could be something like `validates_uniqueness_of :model_name, scope: %i[fuel_type brand], message: "the given name already exists"`

Answer (score 5):

To Rails 4 the correct code with new hash pattern

```
validates :column_name, uniqueness: {scope: [:brand_id, :fuel_type_id]}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would make it this way:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :model_name, :scope => {:brand_id, :fuel_type_id}
```

because it makes more sense for me:

- there should not be duplicated "model names" for combination of "brand" and "fuel type", vs
- there should not be duplicated "brands" for combination of "model name" and "fuel type"

but it's subjective opinion.

Of course if brand and fuel_type are relationships to other models (if not, then just drop "_id" part). With uniqueness validation you can't check non-db columns, so you have to validate foreign keys in model.

You need to define which attribute is validated - you don't validate all at once, if you want, you need to create separate validation for every attribute, so when user make mistake and tries to create duplicated record, then you show him errors in form near invalid field.

Comment: Hi, I think you're correct, but I'm not clear on how the logic works.  I get the sense of validating on "unique model per brand and fuel type," but I don't get why it's wrong to say, "unique brand per model and fuel type." Hmm.

Comment: Yeah, I have the same question as @tidelake. Why every response said to `validate model_name` with `:scope => {:brand_id, :fuel_type_id}`? Why not the same way the OP mentioned validate `:brand` with `:scope => {:model_name, :fuel_type}` ? Why the proposed order is different from the OP's question? I do not see what's the problem or way all answer say to validate `model_name` instead of `brand`!!!

Answer (score 3):

Piecing together the other answers and trying it myself, this is the syntax you're looking for:
`validates :brand, uniqueness: { scope: [:model_name, :fuel_type] }`
I'm not sure why the other answers are adding `_id` to the fields in the scope. That would only be needed if these fields are representing other models, but I didn't see an indication of that in the question. Additionally, these fields can be in any order. This will accomplish the same thing, only the error will be on the `:model_name` attribute instead of `:brand`:
`validates :model_name, uniqueness: { scope: [:fuel_type, :brand] }`

Comment: Correct, appending _id is not necessary in the case of columns.

Answer (score 2):

Using this validation method in conjunction with `ActiveRecord::Validations#save` does not guarantee the absence of duplicate record insertions, because uniqueness checks on the application level are inherently prone to race conditions.

This could even happen if you use transactions with the 'serializable' isolation level. The best way to work around this problem is to add a unique index to the database table using `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements#add_index`. In the rare case that a race condition occurs, the database will guarantee the field's uniqueness.