# How to create a Report Class for handling user abuse, fake profile, inappropriate photos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want my users to be able to report other users who have fake profiles, inappropriate photos, use abusive language etc. I was thinking of creating a Report class which would capture this activity. I am just not sure about the associations.

For example, each user can report another user only once. But a lot of users can report a given user. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have a Report model with polymorphic association with others

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reportable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end

class Photo  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reports, as: :reportable
end

class Profile  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reports, as: :reportable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reports                 # Allow user to report others
  has_many :reports, as: :reportable # Allow user to be reported as well
end
```

Your `reports` table will have fields like:

```
id, title, content, user_id(who reports this), reportable_type, reportable_id
```

To make sure an user can only report one instance of one type once(Say an user can only report another user's profile once), just add this validation in Report model

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: [:reportable_type, :reportable_id]
```

These settings should be able to satisfy the requirements.

*For validation part, thanks to [Dylan Markow at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4871184)*

Comment: You can't have to association with the same name. The user model should be something like:

`has_many :given_reports, class_name: "Report"`