# Rails Multiple Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model with two columns 'name' and 'size'. I am trying to validate the uniqueness of size only if name and size together doesn't exist in database.

For example.

Name = Shirt and Size = L are in database then Name = Shirt and Size = L shouldn't pass the unique validation rather Name = Pant and Size = L should pass the uniqueness.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870961/validate-uniqueness-of-multiple-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can do just like that

```
validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :size,
message: "should be unique" }
```

Comment: Thanks, its saved my day.

Comment: your welcome man

Answer (score 2):

if you want to scope with single column then:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :size, message: "should be unique"
```

for multiple columns:

```
validates :name, uniqueness: {scope: [:size, :attr1, :attr2]}
```