# Rails uniqueness constraint on two column values in different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to know the best way to have an uniqueness constraint enforced on two related model attributes in rails **that are both no primary keys**

```
class Parent > ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children
  :name
end

class Child > ApplicationRecord
  :name
end
```

I want to enforce that (parent.name, child.name) is unique for every parent. e.g.

- `(parent1, child1)` and `(parent2, child1)` is allowed
- `(parent1, child1)` and `(parent1, child1)` is a violation

Ideally, I would enforce this in Postgres, however I have only seen the option to add uniqueness constraints on multiple columns of the same table.

Alternatively, I have written a custom validator for rails that does what I want, but this is cumbersome. There needs to be a better solution...

For completeness, here is the constraints validator which requires one to add a `children` function to a model returning the list of children.

```
class NamePairValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    record.children.values.each do |model_children|
      names = model_children.to_a.collect {|model| model.name}
      if (names.select{|name| names.count(name) > 1 }.size > 0)
        record.errors[:name] << 'Path leading to this resource has no unique name'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

(in Parent.rb)

```
def children
  {children: :children}
end
```

Migrations:

```
class CreateDomains < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :domains do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :domain_type
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :subjects do |t|
      t.string     :name
      t.string     :subject_type
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateJoinTableDomainSubject < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :domains, :subjects do |t|
      t.index [:domain_id, :subject_id]
      t.index [:subject_id, :domain_id]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show how you wrote migrations file for both your models? Because you could also add an index to be sure of the integrity at a DB level e.g https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations

Comment: If you want to do it on database level you could change `parent_id` column and `child_id` into `parent_name` and `child_name` columns and add unique constraints on them. With some ActiveRecord hackery it is possible to use those columns as foreign keys. I'm not sure about this solution it is just a thought.

Comment: Thx! I think you got a pivot table! That's why Nithin's answer does not work. Please have a look at this link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association. It might help you with the syntax and the relation

Comment: My solution won't work with pivot table unfortunately.

Comment: Any suggestions how I might go about implementing a generic solution for more than 2 levels deep? e.g. A has many B, B has many C, C has many D. A, B, C, and D all have a name attribute. The path resembles that of a REST-full resource. All A, B, C and D models have a ID field as well.

e.g. a/b must be unique, but also a/b/c and a/b/c/d

Answer (score 3):

I just used similar one in my code

```
validates :child_name, uniqueness: { scope: :parent_id }
```

More..

(i) https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of

(ii) [Validate uniqueness of multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870961/validate-uniqueness-of-multiple-columns)

Comment: For clarity, in which model do I add this validation (Parent, or Child) ?

Comment: `Child` model, also `child_name` is a example attr

Comment: Suggestion does not seem to work in my case. Got `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column subjects.domain_id does not exist` (In my situation I have Domain as Parent, and Subject as Child). Got error when running `db:migrate db:seed`

Comment: So what is the name of the foreign key column that connect Subject to Domain in your code? Use this instead.

Comment: @RobertPankowecki I have added the migrations to the initial question. This should clarify how Domain is connected to Subject I hope.

Comment: @KevinvandenBekerom how do you know which domain is connected to which subject? Based on the same `name` ? I don't understand which column from `subjects` references which column from `domains` ?

Comment: @RobertPankowecki I believe rails enforces this by the Rails Models. As you can see, there is a table connecting Domains to Subjects based on id.

Comment: @KevinvandenBekerom I just realized your are using intermediate table... You should be using `has_many through:` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` in such case http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

Insipered by [the-has-many-through-association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) of the official doc of ruby on rails:

```
class CreateAppointments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :domains do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :domain_type
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :subjects do |t|
      t.string     :name, null: false
      t.string     :subject_type
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :fields do |t|
      t.belongs_to :domain, index: true
      t.belongs_to :subject, index: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Note**

- I took the initative to rename your model `JoinTableDomainSubject` by `Field` to be more readable.
- I also force `name` field not be `nil` to check uniqueness.
  (adding `null: false` in migrations files and `validates :name, presence: true` in both models)

Now the dedicated classes:

```
class Subject < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :fields
  has_many :domains, through: :fields

  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Domain < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :fields
  has_many :subjects, through: :fields

  validates :name, presence: true
end

class Field < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :domain
  belongs_to :subject

  validate :domain_and_subject_names_uniqueness

  private

  def domain_and_subject_names_uniqueness
    if class.includes(:domain, subject)
            .where(domain: { name: domain.name }, subject: { name: subject.name })
            .exists?
      errors.add :field, 'duplicity on names'
    end
  end
end
```

Since the models are associated, I can use `Field.first.domain` to access `Domain` model of a given `Field` and *vice versa*.

Comment: Usage changed of adding subject to domain. I did: `@domain.subjects << Subject.new(params)
@domain.save`. This does not seem to work anymore...

Comment: Yes. Got this error: `NoMethodError in SubjectsController#create`
`undefined method subject_name' for #<Field:0x00000005efca68> Did you` `mean? subject`

Comment: Moving the validation to Subject model, and scoping to domain_id also doesn't work sadly...

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, `subject_name` does not exists. You can remove `validates_uniqueness_of :subject_name scope: domain_name` and do a custom check, which is not very efficient. Sorry, I'm working on something better

Comment: @KevinvandenBekerom I tried to edit my answer with a custom validator but I'm unsure of what it will do. Please inform me if you succeed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149723/discussion-between-owl-max-and-kevin-van-den-bekerom).