# Prevent duplication in rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, duplicates

I got addresses hash. I am building addresses via nested attributes.
If address hash is duplicate(i.e. address1, zip, country, city) combo already exists, then skip and go for next address hash and create.
I want to write it in a model. 
Custom Validation will halt the execution.
What is the other option to achieve the same

Comment: add unique indexed on db level, catch the exception (ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique) and handle it.

Comment: It sounds like you you need a [callback](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) rather than an validation to handle this.

Comment: I know but I do not want the execution to be halted. I just want to ignore that hash

Comment: I think, I should ignore the hash in a before_save callback

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validate uniqueness of multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870961/validate-uniqueness-of-multiple-columns)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870961/validate-uniqueness-of-multiple-columns/29961501#29961501

Answer (score 1):

```
def insert_address_with_hash(hash)
  Address.create!(hash)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e
  puts 'Ignore dups'
end
```

and Migration (template)

```
class AddUniqIndexOnAdresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :addresses, [:address1, :zip, :country, :city], :unique => true
  end
end
```

Be sure you don't have nonunique rows in the table, the migration wont work.